# elasticsearch query for newest index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Elasticsearch newbie.

I would like to query for the newest index.
Every day logstash creates new indices with a naming convention something like: our_sales_data-%{dd-mm-yyyy}% or something very close. Se I end up with lots of indices like:

> our-sales_data-14-09-2015
>   our-sales-data-15-09-2015
>   our-sales-data-16-09-2015

and so on.

I need to be able to query for the newest index. Obviously I can query for and retrieve all the indices with 'our-sales-data*' in the name.. but I only want to return the very newest one and no other.

Possible?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to query the list of indices - http://localhost:9200/_aliases - and then parse out the index name from here, returning the max.  There is no dedicated API at this point that lists out indices,and ES has no real concept of how index name applies to dates and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Well the preferred method would be to compute the latest index name from client side by resolving the date in our_sales_data-%{dd-mm-yyyy}%.

Another solution would be to run a sort query and get one of the latest document. You can infer the index from the index name of the document.

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "sort": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a search alias and a write alias. The write alias is technically always the latest until we roll it over and add a new one into the this alias.

Our search alias contains all the previous indexes plus the latest index (also in write).

Could you do something like this and then just query the write alias?